# Optimal keymap while using intellij idea on linux and mac

Tags: intellij-idea

I just started using IntelliJ IDEA and want to know what is the best keymap while using IDEA on both Linux and OS X systems. The problem is that I want to learn hotkeys for both Linux and OS x and don't know what to choose.

Comment: Compare this two keymaps
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

There's a differences, for example. between "Delete line at caret", in Linux it's Ctrl+ Y, in

Comment: There are two predefined keymaps for OS X (Mac OS X, Mac OS X 10.5+), see Settings/Keymap. One is more similar to the Windows/Linux keymap so using it is the best option if you frequently use other systems while the other one (10.5+) is more customized to fit in with rest of the OS X shortcuts (e.g. Command + Delete deletes line instead of Command + Y and so on). This keymap is IMHO better if you primarily use IntelliJ on OS X, because it feels more natural if you are already used to other OS X shortcuts.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt That sounds like a reasonable answer.

Comment: Here is the question I've been searching. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be a litle bit subjective topic, but here is some information which might help you decide:

There are two main different predefined keymaps for OS X in IntelliJ (you can find them in *Settings/Keymap*).

- Mac OS X
- Mac OS X 10.5+

The *Mac OS X* keymap is similar to Linux/Windows keyboard. So if you need to switch between multiple systems this one is probably better for you.

The *Mac OS X 10.5+* keyboard is designed to fit it into the OS X ecosystem so if you are used to general OS X shortcuts, this one will feel more natural and you will easily guess a lot of shortcuts.

Here is a reference for the [Mac OS X 10.5+](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) keymap.